# Why do we need "は" in "とは思う"

Tags: particle-は

I do not know the grammatical meaning of "は" and when to add a "は" in between  the quotative particle and the verb, namely "とは思う".

Here is the example sentence without "は",

> > 拡大終了か**と**思われた西之島にまだ拡大の望みはある事が判明

And the example sentence with "は".

> > Q: 売れない商品は削除すべき？
> >
> > A:削除される方も多いか**とは**思われますが、残しておくことをおすすめ致します！

Answer (score 2):

Simply, は in this type of とは is a contrast marker. ～とは is commonly used with だが, けれども, etc.

> - 悪くないと**は**言ったが、最高だと**は**言っていない。
> - 勝ちたいと**は**思うが、難しいだろう。
> - 食べたいと**は**思いますよ。
>     Well, I want to eat it. (But...)
>     (contrast implied; there is a reason he cannot eat it)

Of course とは has other usages, 「彼が学校の先生だった**とは**驚いた。」「チワワ**とは**犬の一種です。」

Comment: I guess last two sentences can be explained as 「彼が学校の先生だった**というのは**驚いた。」「チワワ**というのは**犬の一種です。」, am I right?