# What does とは do in this sentence 「ちなみに俺はどちらも見ようとは思わない」

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-は

From Quintessential Quintuplets (Season 2, ep.3, 9:30)
Character A was describing movies that they saw to someone when Character B said this about those movies.

> ちなみに俺はどちらも見ようとは思わない

If I were to try to translate:

> I wouldn't think of watching of watching either (of those movies).

What does とは do in this sentence? If the sentence didn't have は after と, I would have a much easier time understanding, but I don't know what changes about the sentence when it's とは vs と.

There are a lot of resources on the internet regarding ようと grammar rules but again, I don't know if and how they change when it's とは

Comment: dup? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58376/45489

Comment: That actually answers my question thank you. @sundowner